# How do you re-export a original system call with a different name on aix?

Tags: aix

How do you re-export a original system call with a different name on aix?

Answer (score 1):

System call extension is a unique feature of AIX - it explicitly allow you to write a new kernel extension to replace the old original system call, so that henceforth (from the time the kernel extension is loaded) all system call to the "old" name, will call the new one instead.  To retain reference to the old system call, therefore it is necessary to remember the address first before overwriting it with the new system call - which is meant by the following article "using two kernel module":

http://qasim.zaidi.me/2009/05/overriding-system-call-in-aix.html

More AIX-specific info here:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.kernelext/doc/kernextc/kernex_binding.htm

Answer (score 0):

The simple cheat method is to just #define it.

If that can't work then look at LD_PRELOAD for examples, eg:
http://neworder.box.sk/newsread.php?newsid=13857